# Update table with data from another table using inner join

Tags: update, table

I have two tables and I need to update one of them with respect to the id's of the second table.

First table, `successlog`:

```
Id     pid      shiftid
1       2          
2       2          
3       2          
4       5          
5       5
6       6
7       6
```

Second table, `employeelist`:

```
Id    pId      shiftid
1      2          1
2      5          1
3      6          2
```

I need to update the first table's `shiftid` using the `pid` in the two tables.

I am using this query but it is not working:

```
UPDATE successlog
SET successlog.shiftid = employeelist.shiftid
FROM successlog
INNER JOIN employeelist
ON successlog.pid=employeelist.pId;
```

Comment: Define "not working". Also indicate the DBMS in question, as some use non-standard syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember carefully the structure of the update statement in sql ;)

Try this:

```
UPDATE successlog 
INNER JOIN employeelist
ON successlog.pid=employeelist.pId 
SET successlog.shiftid = employeelist.shiftid
```

Comment: This might have worked but it is **not** standard SQL. (looks like MySQL's UPDATE syntax to me)